# How to print data from database using Struts programming and to display on ftl page

Tags: java, html, jdbc, struts2, freemarker

I'm trying to print data from database using Struts programming and to display on ftl page

```
public class DisplayAction{

private List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

public List<String> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<String> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String execute() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    DisplayUtilService du = new DisplayUtilService();
    ResultSet rs = du.method();

    while (rs.next()) {

        data.add(rs.getString(1));
        data.add(rs.getString(2));
        data.add(rs.getString(3));
        data.add(rs.getString(4));

    }

    // data.add("message");
    if (data.size() > 0)
        return "success";
    return "failure";

}

}
```

To display the POOLNAME and Description to display on Freemarker Template page

```
private List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

public List<String> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<String> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String execute() throws SQLException {

    DisplayUtilService du = new DisplayUtilService();
    ResultSet rs = du.poolName();

    while (rs.next()) {
        data.add(rs.getString("POOLNAME"));// poolname is one of the column
                                            // of table
        data.add(rs.getString("DESCRIPTION"));

    }

    if (data.size() > 0)
        return "success";enter code here
    return "failure";

}

}
```

The content of that table POOLNAME and DESCRIPTION should be printed on this page

Here am facing a problem to display the DESCRIPTION and the POOLNAME, as in the
image and please find the image in the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg4f5.jpg) am not getting proper resource.

[image: 1]

Comment: here am able to fetch the data to the FTL page. The problem is am getting the data from database as a list and am fetching the data as below code                                                                                                                                                                                                

<h1>Pool Name Details.</h1>
</div>
<form action="" method="post" charset="UTF-8">
<#list data as message>
${message}
</#list>
</form>
But i have to display am i shown in figure. Please help me

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Its just simple ..i have to fetch the data from oracle database using struts and i have to display data as i given in the image., Sir am not getting any resource to find the solution . So please help me. It would be a great help for me.

Comment: With the above program i am able to fetch the data in to a ftl page and am getting that data as a list . But i don't know how to align it as in a figure.

Comment: You're using the wrong data structure to pass it to the template; you *could* do it like this, but I wouldn't. Use a DTO that has proper fields and put *those* into a list.

Comment: Can i get sample i am not getting?

Comment: Can i get some sample code i am not getting? thanks

Comment: Make a class that has the same properties as the database columns, e.g., pool name and description. Build a list of those DTOs. Pass that list to the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data returned from the db layer should be structured as objects. You cannot use just `List<String>` to hold the data because you want to show data in a tabular format. Create some object to hold the column values

```java
public class Message {

    private String poolName;
    private String description;

    public Message (String poolName, String description){
       this.poolName = poolName;
       this.description = description;
    }

    public User getPoolName() {
        return poolName;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Change the data structure

```java
private List<Message> data = new ArrayList<Message>();

public List<Message> getData() {
    return data;
}
```

Fill the data

```java
while (rs.next()) {
    Message m = new Message(
    rs.getString("POOLNAME"),// poolname is one of the column
                                        // of table
    rs.getString("DESCRIPTION"));
    data.add(m);

}
```

If you want to return freemarker result, the action configuration should have a corresponding result type.

```xml
<action name="display" class="DisplayAction">
  <result type="freemarker">/messages.ftl</result>
</action>
```

the result file contains a table that shows a data object on each record.

```xml
<table>
<tr>
    <td>POOLNAME</td>
    <td>DESCRIPTION</td>
</tr>
<@s.iterator value="%{data}">
<tr>
    <td>
        <@s.property value="%{poolName}" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <@s.property value="%{description}" />
    </td>
</tr>
</@s.iterator>
</table>
```